# Cannot build a signed apk from flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to generate a signed apk from flutter application. But I  am getting some unexpected error, which i haven't seen before. cannot sort it out. Anyone please help. Here attached the portion of error log

```
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/frontend/kernel_translation_helper.cc: 1642: error: vm.inferred-type.metadata metadata is allowed in precompiled mode only
version=3.1.3 (stable) (Tue Sep 26 14:25:13 2023 +0000) on "windows_simarm"
pid=10180, thread=-1, isolate_group=isolate(01262D88), isolate=(nil)(00000000)
os=windows, arch=arm, comp=no, sim=yes
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
fp=efe768, sp=efe748, pc=7919d2
  pc 0x007919d2 fp 0x00efe768 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x00698530 fp 0x00efe778 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0097a5ee fp 0x00efe7c8 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0097a608 fp 0x00efe7f4 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0097ad38 fp 0x00efe868 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x00719a07 fp 0x00efe890 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0071c0e1 fp 0x00efe9c4 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0071ce04 fp 0x00efec3c Unknown symbol
  pc 0x006e4a3f fp 0x00efecb0 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x006e579d fp 0x00efed24 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0073f1d2 fp 0x00efed58 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0069afee fp 0x00eff000 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0069acdc fp 0x00eff054 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0073a49c fp 0x00eff310 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x006eefe7 fp 0x00eff3a4 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x006ef211 fp 0x00eff3f8 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x009aef76 fp 0x00eff73c Unknown symbol
  pc 0x009af401 fp 0x00eff7d8 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x006919a9 fp 0x00eff8cc Unknown symbol
  pc 0x009b872d fp 0x00eff914 Unknown symbol
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/frontend/kernel_translation_helper.cc: 1642: error: vm.inferred-type.metadata metadata is allowed in precompiled mode only
  pc 0x7591fcc9 fp 0x00eff924 BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
  pc 0x77277c6e fp 0x00eff980 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath+0x11e
  pc 0x77277c3e fp 0x00eff990 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath+0xee
-- End of DumpStackTrace
version=3.1.3 (stable) (Tue Sep 26 14:25:13 2023 +0000) on "windows_simarm64"
pid=8056, thread=-1, isolate_group=isolate(0000025A3F0A93B0), isolate=(nil)(0000000000000000)
os=windows, arch=arm64, comp=yes, sim=yes
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
fp=a43431d8d0, sp=a43431d8d0, pc=7ff621ed1622
  pc 0x00007ff621ed1622 fp 0x000000a43431d8d0 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/frontend/kernel_translation_helper.cc: 1642: error: vm.inferred-type.metadata metadata is allowed in precompiled mode only
version=3.1.3 (stable) (Tue Sep 26 14:25:13 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"
pid=16512, thread=-1, isolate_group=isolate(0000029CBD469E10), isolate=(nil)(0000000000000000)
os=windows, arch=x64, comp=yes, sim=no
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
fp=f6c9f6d880, sp=f6c9f6d880, pc=7ff7e33116f2
  pc 0x00007ff7e33116f2 fp 0x000000f6c9f6d880 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073740791
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073740791
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073740791
Target android_aot_release_android-x64 failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073740791
Target android_aot_release_android-arm failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073740791
Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073740791


> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:cleanMergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :path_provider_android:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :path_provider_android:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher_android:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:createFullJarRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:createFullJarRelease
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:createFullJarRelease
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :path_provider_android:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :path_provider_android:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :path_provider_android:createFullJarRelease
> Task :path_provider_android:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :qr_code_scanner:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:createFullJarRelease
> Task :qr_code_scanner:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :safetynet_attestation:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:createFullJarRelease
> Task :safetynet_attestation:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :share_plus:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:createFullJarRelease
> Task :share_plus:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :shared_preferences_android:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:createFullJarRelease
> Task :shared_preferences_android:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :url_launcher_android:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :url_launcher_android:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher_android:createFullJarRelease
> Task :url_launcher_android:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :path_provider_android:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher_android:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared_preferences_android:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_maps_flutter_android:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :share_plus:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :safetynet_attestation:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher_android:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :path_provider_android:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :qr_code_scanner:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_windowmanager:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.0.1-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.0.1-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 30s
280 actionable tasks: 67 executed, 213 up-to-date
```

Tried

Flutter clean

Flutter pub get

Flutter upgrade

Almost all kind of flutter related commands

Comment: Try flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Comment: Tried this one also. Still not working

Comment: Could this [help](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27239)?